# Swiftui layouts on iPhone and iPad are different

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout, navigation, swiftui

I have tested the same code on two real devices (iPhone and iPad) and got two different layouts. Could somebody explain this difference?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.yellow
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Content View").font(.largeTitle)
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination:SecondView()) {
                          Text("Go to Detail View").font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }

            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination:ContentView()) {
            ZStack {
                Color.green
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Detail View").font(.largeTitle)
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination:ContentView()) {
                        Text("Go to Content View").font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Screens iPad:

[image]
[image]

Screens iPhone:

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you are new to iOS, see first https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/ Your question is not Swift / SwiftUI related.

Comment: :-) especially this part https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/

Answer (score 1):

Using NavigationStack instead of NavigationView should fix it